# I need some help on SFTP file transfer using loadrunner 11

Tags: sftp, loadrunner

There is a project that will involve sftp file transfers to a server. I have tried using ftp protocol and chose winscp.exe - sftp as my program to record. There were events being recorded however there is nothing generated after I finished recording.

If ftp protocol is not the answer to sftp file transfers can anybody give me some insight or tips on how I can do loadtests using LR on sftp file transfers?

I am using Loadrunner 11 for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

LoadRunner *FTP Protocol* doesn't support *SFTP*. It only supports *FTP* and *FTPS* (*FTP* over *SSL*). You could try to load-test an SFTP server using PuTTY' **psftp** tool or similar console client and C funcions like **popen**/**write**/**read**, which are available in any LoadRunner C script regardless of protocol. You might use *CVuser Protocol* to write such script.

Check this old but still somewhat useful [forum discussion](http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Number=673924&page=0) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything can be recorded.  Some have to be programmed.  Seek an API solution for sftp which runs in C, VB, JavaScript or Java, all of which may be implemented in LoadRunner

Answer (score 0):

You can do sftp using Java vuser protocol. You need to write java code to transfer files. The following code snippet might be helpful.

```
import lrapi.lr;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class Actions
{

public int init() throws Throwable {
    return 0;
}//end of init


public int action() throws Throwable {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = jsch.getSession("userId", "HOST",PORT);

        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        session.setPassword("Password");

        session.connect();

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        sftpChannel.cd("Directory to upload files");
        System.out.println("Connection Established");

        File file = new File("Local folder to upload files");
        sftpChannel.put(new FileInputStream(file),file.getName());
        sftpChannel.exit();
        session.disconnect();
        }
    catch (JSchException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    return 0;
}

public int end() throws Throwable {
    return 0;
}//end of end
```

}